# Can I use a bench power supply as a substitute for a 9V DC adapter?

Tags: power-supply, audio, guitar-pedal, testbench

I want to test a guitar pedal but I don’t have a 9V adapter around - but I do have access to a DC power supply.

[image: Bench Power Supply]

Is it possible* to alligator clip the +ve to the power terminal and ground to the chassis and power the pedal that way?

I’ve scoured the internet and I’ve nowhere else to turn! Thanks in advance.

EDIT: *possible and safe!

Comment: Yes but use +,-  which is floating from gnd

Comment: thank you Tony - where do I connect -ve? The chassis?

Comment: The banana jacks are labelled {- GND +} so {BLK x RED}

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 the OP is asking if you can connect PSU negative to the chassis of the pedal

Comment: A battery is a floating supply, so why not use the +/- terminals to keep that.  Your photo shows the + and earth ground connection.  Not sure that will work, usually you have to connect the earth gnd to the - terminal if you want to include the earth ground in the circuit.

Comment: Okay, I understand the point regarding the floating supply, but where do I connect -ve? I’m guessing the coaxial power connection has both + and - inside the socket, so is this a no-go without the proper adapter?

Comment: + to+, - to-. ground here is real ground. Connect it to chassis. Use coloured wires, + is red, - is black. Wrong polarity damage the device.

Comment: Round connector usually plus inside, minus outside. But check carefully, it should be market on enclosure, near connector.

Comment: If you connect it with a small inline fuse you may be less likely to fry the device if you connect it with the wrong polarity.  Especially older guitar pedals are often quite easy to open up and maintain, so if you're not sure of polarity from the markings on it, you can find out from what's inside.

Comment: Also worth noting that although 9V batteries are the devil, a lot of guitar pedals will run off one for a decent period of time.

Comment: Your question is about the pedal power connections yet you show the power supply with the wrong connection for -V.  Coaxial plugs are easy to get  or cut off with pigtails from old ones.   Did you want to show a photo of the pedal power jack? or can you get clip on the pin without shorting out to gnd inside the coaxial barrel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes.  That's pretty much what bench power supplies are for.

Set the current limit to something low.  Set the voltage to 9V before you make the connection.  Make sure you get the + and - the right way round.

You need to use the + and - outputs.  + and GND alone won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you! I’ve only used bench power supplies with “in-progress” circuits (on breadboards, vero etc). Where do I connect the -ve lead though? Can I attach it to the chassis, i.e. are “ground” and -ve analogous in this context, insofar as they are the return path of the current?

Comment: Connect the + and - to the battery terminals, or to the mains adaptor terminals if that's easier.  You can connect the GND to the case if you want, and that might reduce stray noise being picked up.